# How to display title and snippet on a google maps composable marker, without clicking on it?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using the new google maps integration [library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/maps-compose) with jetpack compose, however I want to modify a behavior of my markers: when the map initializes I want to show the information of my marker without having to click on it. Currently the map starts like this:

[image]

When I click on the highlighted mark it looks like this:

[image]

**The result I expect is that this bookmark appears with this information without me necessarily having to click on it.**

The code I use to render the map with the markers is this:

```kotlin
GoogleMap(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxHeight(0.9f)
        .fillMaxWidth(),
    cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState
) {
    coordinates.forEach { (hotelName, coordinate) ->
        var alpha = 0.5f
        if (highlightedMarkerPosition == LatLng(coordinate[0], coordinate[1]))
            alpha = 1f

        Marker(
            position = LatLng(coordinate[0], coordinate[1]),
            title = hotelName,
            snippet = uiState.bestHotelAndValue?.second.toString(),
            alpha = alpha
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: @MehulKanzariya not yet, consider to give +1 in this question to make it more visible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

save the `MarkerState` into a variable and then call [`showInfoWindow`](https://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-compose/maps-compose/com.google.maps.android.compose/-marker-state/index.html#984542239%2FFunctions%2F1410455054)

like this

```
GoogleMap(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxHeight(0.9f)
        .fillMaxWidth(),
    cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState
) {
    coordinates.forEach { (hotelName, coordinate) ->
        var alpha = 0.5f
        if (highlightedMarkerPosition == LatLng(coordinate[0], coordinate[1]))
            alpha = 1f
        
        HotelMarker(
            LatLng(coordinate[0], coordinate[1]),
            hotelName,
            uiState.bestHotelAndValue?.second.toString(),
            alpha
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun HotelMarker(position: LatLng, title: String, snippet: String?, alpha: Float){
    val markerState = rememberMarkerState(null, position)
    Marker(
        state = markerState,
        title = title,
        snippet = snippet,
        alpha = alpha
    )
    markerState.showInfoWindow()
}
```